# Why Swift requires override of designated initializer of generic superclass?

Tags: swift, generics, compiler-errors, initializer

According to Apple's documentation Swift does not necessary require override of initializer. In a following code example `Bar` inherits initializer of `Foo`:

```
class Foo {
  let value: Int
  init(value: Int = 5) {
    self.value = value
  }
}

class Bar: Foo {
}
```

As soon as we add some generic into `Foo` such as `class Foo<T> {` Xcode provides us a error `Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass`. Is there a documentation or swift evolution discussion that explains why it is happening?

---

**Update.** It seems that generic is not a major cause for override requirement. Here are an option how to define a class with generic that does not require override of designated initializer:

```
protocol FooProtocol {
    associatedtype T
}

class Foo<U>: FooProtocol {
    typealias T = U

    let value: Int
    init(value: Int, otherValue: T) {
        self.value = value
        self.otherValue = otherValue
    }
}

class Bar: Foo<Int> {
}
```

However there is another interesting observation of behavior. Defining initializer like following cause override requirement:

```
init(value: Int = 5) {
    self.value = value
}
```

The funny thing thing that adding one more parameter as following into such designated initializer cause this override requirement to disappear:

```
init(value: Int = 5, otherValue: T) {
    self.value = value
}
```

**Update 2**. I can not find a logical explanation to this behavior, at this point I reported it as Compiler bug — https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1375

Comment: I did some more testing and the problem appears to be _the default value_. Take the `=5` out of your examples and _none_ of them result in the compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

I actually filled a bug report for inheriting from generic class:

[image]

It was back in **November last year** and didn't get an answer yet, so ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thanks. It is definitely helpful to know that I am not alone experiencing this issue. Meanwhile I can not count this message as an answer, as it neither documentation nor swift evolution discussion regarding this topic.

Comment: I agree: very interesting, but this is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly a bug. Moreover, although the bug is *elicited* by subclassing a generic, its proximate *cause* is the default value. This compiles just fine:

```
class Foo<T> {
    let value: Int
    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class Bar: Foo<String> {
}
```

But this does not:

```
class Foo<T> {
    let value: Int
    init(value: Int = 5) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class Bar: Foo<String> {
}
```

That sort of arbitrary distinction without a difference is a sure indication that this is a compiler bug.

Comment: I suspect, though of course I can't prove, that behind the scenes what's proving confusing for the compiler is that to call `init(value: Int = 5)` without a `value` would be the same as calling `init`. I don't know why that's confusing in the case of a generic, but that's the direction your examples seem to point to.